# How i can get all the documents inside our site collection which are OneNote documents

Tags: 2013, search, administration, onenote

We have sharepoint 2013 site collection, which have 70 sub-sites. now some document libraries contain OneNote documents. so i want to search all the site collection and its sub-sites, to be able to get all the OneNote documents. now i try to do a searching using this search criteria `.one` but i got many documents which are not OneNote. so can i search the site collection using file types?

Comment: Use filetype:one. This will only get the single pages as the acutal file/notebook is a zip with the extension onetoc2. Searching for 'onetoc2' will give you all the links to each notebook, but they are unhelpful as it can be hard to determine what Notebook you actually are opening.

Comment: IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one

Comment: @MarkoTica thanks for the reply. yes inside the built-in search box i typed `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one` and i got a list of one note files. now i do not have much knowledge about OneNote files, but will `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one` covers  onenote document which have extension = `onetoc2`??

Comment: @Christoffer thanks for the reply.. but i did not get your reply ? what do you mean by `ut they are unhelpful as it can be hard to determine what Notebook you actually are opening`?

Comment: You could try with IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one* this will return all files with .one and .onetoc2 (.onetoc2 is OneNote table of contents file)

Comment: @MarkoTica in my case we i run `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one*` & `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one` i will get the same search results... not sure what this means?

Comment: * is wildcard (FileType:one* will return all .one and .onetoc2 files) https://www.techmikael.com/2014/12/limit-search-results-to-documents.html

Comment: @MarkoTica Yes i am already aware of how the `*` work. but i mean in my case since the `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:onetoc2` did not return anything. while `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one*` & `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one` return the same documents. so i can conclude that all the onenote files i have, have the `.one` file type extension ? and i do not have any `.onetoc2` files?

Answer (score 2):

This query will return `.one` files

```
IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one
```

This query will return `.one` and `.onetoc2` files

```
FileType:one*

"*" is wildcard (FileType:one* will return all .one and .onetoc2 files).
```

`IsDocument:TRUE` returning documents `.one` and not `.onetoc2` so you have same results.

https://www.techmikael.com/2014/12/limit-search-results-to-documents.html

Comment: OK thanks for the reply. now i run this search `FileType:one*` and still i am getting the same results as `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one*` & `IsDocument:TRUE FileType:one` .. So my conclusion is that, maybe i do not have `.onetoc2` files. or `.onetoc2` is excluded from the search (although i have never define any thing inside the search service to exlcude `.onetoc2` files!!)